# moz-column-count crashes Firefox

Tags: firefox, css

If I use following code, the Firefox (16.0.1) crashes after some seconds if i refresh the page. If i remove the code, it does not crash. Is there problem with my code or with FF?

```
#wrap{
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 5px;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 5px;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 5px;
}
```

Comment: can you create an example in http://jsfiddle.net for better understanding.

Comment: It only seems to happen for me when nested divs are floating inside columns. Seems like a bug in FF with columns.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try other versions of FF? Other browsers?

Anyway, if Firefox crash, the issue is with Firefox, not your code.

That's like [blaming some simple html](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/33394/how-to-crash-any-version-of-internet-explorer-with-simple-html/)  for causing [any version of IE to crash](http://crashie8.com/).

You should try to pinpoint the exact few line that crash it (is it `-moz-column-count` or `-moz-column-gab`? or is it `column-count`? Or some specific order of css?), make the simplest demo case and [fill a bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org).